# Javascript accessing the main object from withing its property

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var myObj = new function(){
   this.dateInfo = "someinfo";
}
```

and then I have the following properties:

```
myObj.add = function(){
    console.log("Added");
}
 myObj.remove.item = function(key){
  console.log("Item "+key+" removed.");
}
```

The issue is here:

```
myObj.remove.undo = function(key){
    // here I want to use `myObj.add()` function, what should I do?
}
```

In the above (last) function, I want to utilize the `myObj.add()`, how should I refer to it? I know `this` does not do the trick (from inside the `remove.undo()`).

I need help. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you simply go with `removeItem`, `removeUndo`, etc, it will make everything easier. As `this` is dynamic, it's hard to keep track of it when you have many nested objects and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *possible*, because your `myObj` is a singleton — just use it directly, your functions close over the `myObj` variable:

```
myObj.remove.undo = function(key){
    myObj.add(/*...*/);
}
```

Here's a second way, which also relies on `myObj` being a singleton (although this could be modified to support more than one object):

```
myObj.add = function(){
    console.log("Added");
};

myObj.remove = {
    parent: myObj
};

myObj.remove.item = function(key){
  console.log("Item "+key+" removed.");
};

myObj.remove.undo = function(key){
    this.parent.add(/*...*/);
};
```

Again, though, I wouldn't. I'd either:

1. Use `removeItem`, `removeUndo`, etc. as elclanrs suggested.
2. Use `items` and `undos` properties which are the items and "undo"s in question, and give them `add` and `remove` methods (and a reference to their parent object, the way I have with `remove` above.

---

Side note:

```
var myObj = new function(){
    this.dateInfo = "someinfo";
};
```

...is a long and wasteful way to write

```
var myObj = {
    dateInfo: "someinfo"
};
```

The first way creates a function and an additional object, both of which clutter up memory for no good reason (as `myObj` refers to them both, through its prototype, so the JavaScript engine has to keep them in memory):

```
+-----------+  
|   myObj   |  
+-----------+      +-------------+
| __proto__ |----+>|  (object)   |
| dateInfo  |   /  +-------------+       +------------------+
+-----------+   |  | __proto__   |------>| Object.prototype |
                |  | constructor |---+   +------------------+
                |  +-------------+   |
                |                    |
                |                    |   +------------+
                |                    +-->| (function) |
                |                        +------------+
                |                        | __proto__  |---->(omitted, not relevant)
                |                        | prototype  |--+
                |                        +------------+  |
                |                                        |
                +----------------------------------------+
```

The second way doesn't:

```
+-----------+
|   myObj   |
+-----------+    +------------------+
| __proto__ |--->| Object.prototype |
| dateInfo  |    +------------------+
+-----------+
```